# SilverStripe creating DataObject from array is always showing "#"/ hash for the Title field

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. Now I am trying to create DataObject instance from an array. This is how I created.

```
$dataObject = \SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject::create([
   'Title' => 'This is my title',
   'Body' => 'This is the body',
   'Intro' => 'Thi is the intro',
])
```

The object is created. The problem is when I try to access the Title value of the object. I printed out the Title field like this.

```
echo $dataObject->Title;
```

It is printing out # / hash instead of printing out the Title value. When I convert it into array using toMap(), I can see the Title value is there. But I want to get the Title value from the object. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must create our own custom class that extends `DataObject` and use that. `DataObject` does not have a `Title` field, `Body` field, `Intro` field or even a database table to store data in.

For example we could call our class `Course`:

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

class Course extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Body' => 'Text',
        'Intro' => 'Text',
    ];
}
```

Then we can use our `Course` class as follows:

```
$course = Course::create([
   'Title' => 'This is my title',
   'Body' => 'This is the body',
   'Intro' => 'Thi is the intro',
]);

$course->write();

echo $course->Title;
```